# Низкая производительность android эмуляторов на linux сервере

Tags: linux, непрерывная-интеграция, android-emulator, kvm, gitlab-runner

работаю с CI/CD, и запускаю UI тесты. Использую gitlab-ci, в итоге ci имеет такую структуру.
gitlab-ci-runner ( Docker ( тут проект, android-sdk и 3 эмулятора ) )
установил kvm, использую intel-atom-x86 образы, так же навсякий поставил HAXM для linux.
Все работает, но проблема в том что некоторые тесты падают на CI, а локально на пк проходят хорошо.

Во время запуска эмулятора получаю такое предупреждение:

> emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.

хост - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz — 6ядер по 2потока.
loadAverage поднимается выше 12.0 и может достигать отметки 20.
из предупреждения понимаю что это замедляет работу эмуляторов.
Поэтому вопрос - можно ли как-то при создании или запуске эмулятора переопределить конфигурацию эмулятора чтобы он использовал только одно ядро???

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось понизить нагрузку на ядра путем указания --device параметра при создании android эмулятора.
указал: 5.4in FWVGA
теперь я получаю loadAverage 4-6 стабильно, вместо 12 и выше.
Этого мне достаточно, и я могу поднять еще несколько эмуляторов.
Но предупреждение при запуске эмулятора не исчезло.
Поэтому продолжаю ждать предложений по решению данного предупреждения